# How do you use Furigana on the new Anki?

Tags: discussion

I've been trying everything [the extension](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/3918629684)  says to do, but so far I've been drawing blanks on how to get it working. Anyone familiar with it?

Comment: Just a note: A question like this is explicitly on-topic at http://superuser.com .  We pretty much have decided to allow "offtopic but related" questions to stay open on our meta site, but it's not the optimal place for it.

Comment: When you say "get it working", are you talking about displaying furigana? or auto-generating them?

Comment: I won't migrate this, but you *might* want to re-ask it on superuser with some more detail.  I'm not sure if there's enough information to write an answer right now . . .  Is your note type set to Japanese?